# Allow leading and trailing spaces in EDI map testing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing, biztalk, biztalk-2010, edi

I have some data which is being mapped into an EDI format. One issue is the data in one element has leading and trailing spaces, and these are significant. But when I run a test of the map, I get "Current value -        B   427F : [37] Invalid character(s) found in data element" ... the value is `....B...427F` where `.` represents spaces.

I believe the answer is ticking the "Allow leading and trailing zeroes and spaces" in the partner agreement properties ... *is that correct?*

But I can't see any way in the Visual Studio EDIFACT EDI Instance Properties dialog that is displayed when testing the map.

How can I run the map tests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I often work with EDIFACT, but never use the VS.NET validation anymore. I have found that actually deploying the schema/pipeline in BizTalk gives me much better results, often different results as well!

In addition to the above, actually deploying it into BizTalk itself, gets you additional validation options (trailing/leading spaces for example), party validation, etc...

For some reason I never trusted VS EDIFACT validation to be honest.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response. How do you handle testing?

Comment: Agreed.  I can't recall the last time I did Native validation in Visual Studio.  Xml->Xml gets you 95% of the way there, then you clean up the EDI nuances by testing in BizTalk with your agreement, etc.  Some settings are only available in the Agreement so it's mostly unavoidable.

Comment: @SteveC Testing is handled by just redeploying the artifacts to BizTalk over and over again, until I get what is needed. Unfortunately that is the biggest downside to this approach.